# How to manage dynamic id for COMPOSE button in Gmail in Selenium Automated Test

Tags: java, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

The id of COMPOSE button of Gmail is dynamic. So when it is clicked different xpath is recorded by Selenium IDE as follows:

```
//div[@id=':lw']/div/div , //div[@id=':as']/div/div
```

What can be the alternative ways of using the id or xpath?

The following is the HTML for COMPOSE button:

```
<div class="aic" id=":as"><div class="z0"><div tabindex="0" role="button" class="T-I J-J5Ji L3 T-I-KE" style="-moz-user-select: none;" gh="cm">COMPOSE</div></div></div>
```

Comment: ur welcome..Yep its greatly improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for COMPOSE in Gmail

```
ClickAt   |  //div[text()='COMPOSE']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS classes. They do not change in Gmail and this solution won't be locale dependent.

For the compose button the class is "T-I J-J5-Ji L3".

An example using jQuery:

```
$('.T-I.J-J5-Ji.L3').live('click', function () {

     alert('Compose button clicked');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) here.

> Sikuli Script automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image
>   recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when
>   there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Comment: As said above this should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

The following WebDriver Java code should work nicely:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='COMPOSE']")).click();
```

Using Selenium RC with Java:

```
selenium.click("//div[text()='COMPOSE']");
```

Answer (score 0):

google uses dynamic ids for most of the elements. Try using the "Compose" text instead of using the ID.

you can use something like this.
Webelement element = driver.findElementByXpath("//div[text()='COMPOSE']");
element.click();

hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

I have sent an Emil successfully through selenium automation using Gmail Account Below is the script please find it:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

String baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/";
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':jb']/div[@class='z0']/div")).click(); // Compose

selenium.type("//div[@class='wO nr l1']//textarea[@name='to']", "vikramn@gmail.com"); // For To 
selenium.type("//div[@class='aoD az6']//input[@name='subjectbox']", "Wanted to SAY HI"); // For Subject
selenium.type("//div[@class='Ar Au']/div[@class='Am Al editable LW-avf']", "Hi Vikram");// For Message body
selenium.click("//div[@class='J-J5-Ji']/div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3']"); //send
```